# SeekBar in ListView not correctly responding to onStartTrackingTouch

Tags: android, android-listview, android-drawable

I have a ListView (or GridView, it depends on screen size) of custom items, each containing SeekBar. I'm setting OnSeekBarChangeListener and the problem is, that onStartTrackingTouch fires after releasing button or after changing position of thumb (it should be after press). I thought that ListView, or rows of ListView, are stealing the event, but I tried many different solutions and nothing works.

I don't want to even use onStartTrackingTouch. The reason I need this working: when user is pressing the thumb, it changes its state (so user knows he started dragging the thumb). Now, thumb changes its state only when position of it has been changed.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarList);
    list.setAdapter(new Adapter());

    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarOutsideTheList);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.outsideListLbl))
                    .setText("onStop");
            Log.d("seekBarOutsideTheList", "onStop");

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.outsideListLbl))
                    .setText("onStart");
            Log.d("seekBarOutsideTheList", "onStart");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.outsideListLbl))
                    .setText("onChange");
            Log.d("seekBarOutsideTheList", "onChange");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflter;

    public Adapter() {
        layoutInflter = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView label;
        SeekBar seek;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflter.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.label = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.insideListLbl);
            viewHolder.seek = (SeekBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.seekbarInLIst);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        viewHolder.seek
                .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.insideListLbl))
                                .setText("onStop");
                        Log.d("seekBarInsideTheList", "onStop");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.insideListLbl))
                                .setText("onStart");
                        Log.d("seekBarInsideTheList", "onStart");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                            int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.insideListLbl))
                                .setText("onChange");
                        Log.d("seekBarInsideTheList", "onChange");
                    }
                });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SeekBar outside the list" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarOutsideTheList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/outsideListLbl"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/seekbarList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

list_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SeekBar inside the list" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbarInLIst"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/insideListLbl"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and testing, I found out that it's not a bug or error.

First of all, user should be able to scroll the list without any problems. So if he place a finger on seekbar, but doesn't move it horizontally, he is able to scroll the list, because seekbar's events haven't been fired. That's why it behaves like this.

Secondly, the behaviour is different depending on version of API. I tested API 7, 8 and 10, and on them *onStartTrackingTouch* fires immediately. But on API 16 the first is list scrolling.

In conclusion: the behaviour I wanted to implement is bad behaviour. User should be able to scroll the list with ease. I should rather think, how to change the behaviour on lower APIs, but that's not the topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

add  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in your row item layout if you want both row item click & thumb progress change.

list_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50" />
```

AdapterSeek.java

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflter;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public AdapterSeek() {
        layoutInflter = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return seekbarval.length;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return seekbarval[position];
    }

    class PlaceHolder {
        TextView labell;
        SeekBar seek;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     * android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        PlaceHolder placeHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflter.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            placeHolder = new PlaceHolder();
            placeHolder.labell = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lbl);
            placeHolder.seek = (SeekBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
            convertView.setTag(placeHolder);
        } else
            placeHolder = (PlaceHolder) convertView.getTag();
        placeHolder.labell.setText(" No. " + position);
        placeHolder.seek.setProgress(seekbarval[position]);
        placeHolder.seek
                .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        Log.e("onStopTrackingTouch",
                                "" + seekBar.getProgress());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        Log.e("onStartTrackingTouch",
                                "" + seekBar.getProgress());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                            int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        if (fromUser)
                            Log.e("onProgressChanged", "" + progress);
                    }
                });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

ActivityView.java

```
private int[] seekbarval = new int[] { 100, 20, 80, 50, 40, 10, 0, 70, 30,
        90, 15, 35, 65, 75, 70, 100, 25, 89 };

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testscreen);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarList);
    list.setAdapter(new AdapterSeek());
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android
         * .widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)
         */
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.e("onItemClick", "" + arg2);

        }

    });
```

i tried to give u ans whtevr i understand from your quest... leave comment if req.
and **onStartTrackingTouch** is called on thumb change & **onStopTrackingTouch** is called when i release thumb.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but as You said: "onStartTrackingTouch is called on thumb change". This it not behaviour I want. When You have a single SeekBar, not in ListView, it fires onStartTrackingTouch when thumb is pressed. This default behaviour I want in list, and I don't know why it behaves differently.